# Having trouble aligning texts rotated via CSS within <td>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently modifying Chris Callison-Burch's Amazon Mechanical Turk Word Alignment UI (https://github.com/callison-burch/mechanical_turk_workshop/wiki/word-alignment or http://cs.jhu.edu/~ccb/interface-word-alignment.html ) so that it doesn't use images for rotated source words. I've got the source (English) words successfully rotated, but I'm having trouble aligning them properly. I'd like to have the words wrap around the table, so the English words on the top should be aligned to the top of the table, and those on the bottoms should be aligned to the bottom of the table. Basically, I want it to look like this page (http://cs.jhu.edu/~ccb/interface-word-alignment.html) but with rotated texts instead of rotated images.

You can check the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/BqTJe/

Specifically, I'm rotating the words using the following CSS class:

```
.rotated { 
    display: block; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 20px; 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I'm not quite sure, based on your explanation, what you intend the end result to be. Maybe submit an image that represents your end goal?

Comment: I want it to look like how it does in this: [link](http://cs.jhu.edu/~ccb/interface-word-alignment.html), but use plain texts instead of using images.

Comment: if you put a border around the blocks you're rotating, you'll see that rotation removes the text from document flow - the box doesn't expand vertically to include the text that's overlapping the grey area. you'd have to adjust the height of the line to accomodate the "tallest" line.

Comment: Can you fiddle with the transform-origin property (similar to transform, has a different one for each browser, sigh...)?  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on www.reddit.com/r/css, and this is what I got (thanks www.reddit.com/u/dangoodspeed!)

First you add the following lines to css:

```
table { border-collapse:collapse; margin:100px auto;}
td { border:2px solid white; min-width:20px; min-height:20px;}
table tr:last-child td { overflow:hidden; height:100px; max-width:20px;}
table tr:last-child td div { display:block; text-align:right; width:100px; height:20px; positon:relative; left:-40px;}
```

then you wrap the texts on the bottom of the table with div instead of span.

You can see the fixed version here: http://jsfiddle.net/BqTJe/12/

Note: words cannot be longer than 100px.